# jquery on click loading ext html

Tags: jquery, onload

Hi jquery Gurus I am new to this and I have a very difficult situation Here , Can u help me with this challenge, its very important for me and I am stuck here.
This is the scenario : 3 pages ( index, menu, content)
The index is including the menu
The menu.php has inside a link
Now I want to click on this link and load the content.php in a divission inside the index.php. Is That Possible? I tried the follow but I missing  something.

//This is index.php

```
<div>
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>

 <p>load the content here:</p>
 <ol id="new-nav"></ol>
 </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){         

 $("#test li").click(function (e) {

    // Stop the link from changing the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your jQuery code.

    $("#new-nav").load($(this).attr("href"));
 });

 });
 </script>
```

//This is menu.php

```
 <div id="test">
 <li><a href="content.html">Content</a></li>
 </div>
```

//the content.html is a paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are selecting the li and try to get the href attribute of it :-)

try this

```
$("#test li a:first").click(function (e) {

    // Stop the link from changing the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your jQuery code.

    $("#new-nav").load($(this).attr("href"));
```

});

Comment: YOU ARE A MAGICIAN !!! thank so much for this tip thank u thank u, Where i learn about this syntax for not bother u again? thank u thank u

Comment: hmmm... i dont know... i see you forgot your UL arround your LIs